# Detecting Server Crash With RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I'm new to Java and RMI, but I'm trying to write my app in such a way that there are many clients connecting to a single server.  So far, so good....

But when I close the server (simulating a crash or communication issue) my clients remain unaware until I make my next call to the server.  It is a requirement that my clients continue to work without the server in an 'offline mode' and the sooner I know that I'm offline the better the user-experience will be.

Is there an active connection that remains open that the client can detect a problem with or something similar - or will I simply have to wait until the next call fails?  I figured I could have a 'health-check' ping the server but it seemed like it might not be the best approach.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i'm just trying to learn more about RMI and CORBA but i'm not that far as you are. all i know is that those systems are also built to be less expensive, and as far as i know an active conneciton is an expensive thing.

i would suggest you use a multicast address to which your server sends somehow "i'm still here" but without using TCP connections, UDP should be enough for that purpose and more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a bit when I was writing an RMI app (uni assignment) but I didn't come across any inbuilt functionality for testing whether a remote system is alive. I would just use a UDP heartbeat mechanism for this.

Answer (score 1):

(Untested).  Having a separate RMI call repeatedly into the server, which just does a "wait X seconds" and then return, should be told that the execution has failed when the server is brought down.